# How do we compute the expectation value of momentum for a 1D wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, wavefunction, fourier-transform

I have a 1D wave function $\psi(x)=Ae^{-x^2/a^2}$ and $a$ is just a value of $x$ greater than $0$ and $A$ is the normalization constant, which I found to be $A= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a \, \sqrt{(\pi/2)}}}$.

I can find (expected x) =  $E(x)$ and $E(x^2)$ to get uncertainty in $x$ which is $\sqrt{(E(x^2)-(E(x)^2)}$.

However I am not sure how to do $E(p)$ or the uncertainty in $p$,   $p=$ momentum.

Comment: You need to specify a *potential* $V(x) $to define your system via the schrodinger equation. You cannot find the energy if you don't know the potential function. You do however know the kinetic energy operator, which is just $ {P^2} \over {2 m} $

Answer (score 1):

In the position basis, the momentum operator can be represented as

$$
\hat{p} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$

Therefore, the expected value of the momentum for this wavefunction is simply

$$
E(p) = \langle \psi | \hat{p}|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar\int {\rm d}x\; \psi^*(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x) = 0
$$

and

$$
E(p^2) = \langle \psi | \hat{p}^2|\psi\rangle = -\hbar^2\int {\rm d}x\; \psi^*(x)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(x) = -\frac{1}{a^2}
$$

Comment: $-i\hbar\partial_x$ is **not** the momentum operator. It is the *representation* of the momentum operator on the position basis.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco You are absolutely right, it is just that for this example $|\psi\rangle$ is actually written in the the position basis $\psi(x) = \langle x | \psi \rangle $, so I thought it was a bit redundant. I just updated my answer

Comment: The edit is an improvement, but a more accurate statement is that $\hat p$ acts in the position basis as $$⟨x|\hat p = -i\hbar \frac\partial{\partial x}⟨x|.$$

Comment: For what it's worth, OP probably is not thinking about operators etc. in the abstract way.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty. Sorry, the equality you wrote makes no sense.

Comment: @DanielC You seem to be confused between "I don't understand this" and "this makes no sense". The equation in my previous comment is perfectly correct and has been discussed on this site on multiple occasions.